# EvaluationObject not appearing

Tags: parallelization

By using

```
ParallelSubmit[1 + 2]
```

the output is simply

```
EvaluationObject[16,1+2,<>]
```

I was expecting to see

[image].

Even in the help pages for ParallelSubmit this happens. The figure correctly appears in the help before I do any evaluation, but, after I do it, it changes to the text above. These figures work as monitor to the computations in the parallel kernels. They are not essential, but they are helpful.

I am using Mathematica 12.1.1. The option "Dynamic updating", in the Evaluation menu, is enabled. Is this a known issue? Are there workarounds?

**Update:**
There is a single computer with this issue, I am not sure if it is a particular bug in its instalation, or it is a configuration of some option.

Following @b3m2a1 suggestion, I typed `CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {StyleDefinitions, "Output", DefaultFormatType}]` and the result was `DefaultOutputFormatType`.

Comment: Now I know of two Mathematica users that do not have this issue. Hence possibly there is some way to correct this behaviour...

Comment: What is `CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {StyleDefinitions, "Output", DefaultFormatType}]` or  `CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {StyleDefinitions, "Input", DefaultOuputFormatType}]`?

Comment: @b3m2a1, the first returns `DefaultOutputFormatType`, the second `{}`. Sorry for the delay in answering. At the moment a single computer of mine has this issue, and I spent some time without having contact to it.

Comment: It is difficult for readers to address a problem that they cannot reproduce.

Comment: This problem apparently occurs on only one particular computer.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, yes, I understand. This was an annoying issue that I had, but after reinstalling mathematica it disappeared. It was either a configuration issue or a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Switch between StandardForm and OutputForm.

[image]

Comment: Jean-Pierre, thanks, but which Mathematica version are you using? It did not work for me. Previously, the figure appeared without using // StandardForm.

Comment: 12.1.1.0 on MacOS 10.15.6. , and yes, there is no need to specify StandardForm to get the figure. This is the default.

Comment: It appears it is actually an issue with some configuration of mine. I have two computers with mathematica, and both display this issue. But, like Jean-Pierre, a friend of mine does not have this issue. I still don't know what would be the cause or how to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Some things change to better. In 13.3.1 on Windows 10

```
ParallelSubmit[1 + 2]
```

[image]